# SQL Level the data conditionally

Tags: sql, pivot

I have the following puzzle to solve (an urgent business assignment to be exact)
SQL SERVER 2008

I have a table of this form

```
ID    Market      SubMarket     Value
1       1          1              3
2       1          2              6
3       1          3              2
4       2          23             1
5       2          24             9
```

I have specific MarketIDs and every MarketID has specific SubMarketIDs (maximum 5 - I know how may for each)
eg MarketID 1 has SubMarketIDs 1,2,3
   MarketID 2 has SubMarketIDs 23,24 etc
and each SubMarketID has a variable value

I must transform my data in a fixed table of this type

```
MarketID  SubMarketAvalue   SubMarketBValue   SubMarketCValue....SubMarketEValue

   1              3                 6                2                  null

   2              1                 9               null                null
```

SubMarketAValue must contain the value of the smaller SubMarketID

SubMarketBValue must contain the value of the next bigger SubMarketID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the RDBMS, but you can use the following in SQL Server 2005+, Oracle and PostgreSQL:

```
select market,
  max(case when rn = 1 then value end) as SubMarketAvalue,
  max(case when rn = 2 then value end) as SubMarketBvalue,
  max(case when rn = 3 then value end) as SubMarketCvalue,
  max(case when rn = 4 then value end) as SubMarketDvalue,
  max(case when rn = 5 then value end) as SubMarketEvalue
from 
(
  select id, market, submarket, value,
    row_number() over(partition by market 
                      order by market, submarket) rn
  from yourtable
) x
group by market
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3570a/7)

Comment: That is unbelievably elegant! You saved me tens of if/else clauses! Thank you!